# My Mysql do not know trigger, what can i do?

Tags: mysql, triggers

in the name of god.

hello. i want create a trigger in database on table but mysql do not know trigger.
i use of XAMPP 1.7.3(php 5.3.1,Mysql 5.1.41).

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME ON TABLE_NAME (FOR/BEFOR/AFTER)  {INSERT,UPDATE,...}
...
```

please precision to trigger color on image :

[image: dont know trigger]

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `TR_INSERT`
BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_users`

IF ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_users WHERE username IN ( SELECT username FROM inserted))>1
begin
PRINT 'THIS NAME IS EXISTS'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
end
```

error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_users WHERE username IN ( SELECT username FROM ins' at line 4

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is your problem?

Comment: my problem is mysql dont know trigger.

Comment: MySQL knows triggers. They are good buddies actually.

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER TR_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_users FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF ...`

Comment: excuse me, why when i run tr_Insert mysql show error ?

Comment: And you rollback a transaction that you don't start before.

Comment: please , you send a trriger for me .thanks

Comment: I see what you try to do. Change a MSSQL trigger into a MySQL one. What you do in that trigger can be done by a simple unique key on the `username` column. Then the DB will cancel inserting records that alsready exist.

Comment: thanks for you . but i try this code for test and learning. i run this : 'CREATE TRIGGER TR_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_users 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
IF ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_users WHERE username IN ( SELECT username FROM inserted))>1
ROLLBACK' but show : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROLLBACK' at line 4 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achive the same thing with an unique key on `username`. But for the sake of learing about triggers:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `TR_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_users`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_users WHERE username IN (NEW.username)) > 1
   THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'THIS NAME ALREADY EXISTS';
   END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```